# Angular js order by ID when ID is a string and not an INT

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angular, and I have a list of elements which I'd like to render dynamically.

I have three buttons, and each button calls the same function with a parameter. This parament is the order I want my list to be displayed.

So far so good, everything works as expected.

Everything apart from the ID.

Unfortunately, I get the data from a service and the ID comes back as a string and not as an int, meaning that angular puts "10" before "2".

I feel like having to use a loop to iterate trough my data just to convert the ID from string to int is a step maybe not required and that can potentially slow down the app, especially on old phones with not a lot of processing power (if I am completely wrong, please just let me know).

Here's a quick example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
   {type: "Type 1",
     name: "Name1",
     element: {
       one: {
         id: "10"
       },
       two: {
          location: "US"
       }                    
     }
   },
   {type: "Type 1",
     name: "Name2",
     element: {
       one: {
         id: "2"
       },
       two: {
          location: "UK"
       }                    
     }
   },
   {type: "Type 3",
     name: "Name3",
     element: {
       one: {
         id: "3"
       },
       two: {
          location: "DE"
       }                    
     }
   },
   {type: "",
     name: "Name4",
     element: {
       one: {
         id: "4"
       },
       two: {
          location: "IT"
       }                    
     }
   },
   {type: "Type 1",
     name: "Name4",
     element: {
       one: {
         id: "5"
       },
       two: {
          location: ""
       }                    
     }
   }
  ]

  $scope.ChangeOrder = function(order) {
    switch (order) {
      case 'id':
        return $scope.order = parseInt('element.one.id');
      case 'location':
        return $scope.order = 'element.two.location';
      case 'type':
        return $scope.order = 'type';
    }
  };     
}]);
```

and the **HTML**:

```
 <div class="container">
          <div ng-repeat="d in data | orderBy: order">
          {{d.element.one.id}} - {{d.name}} - {{d.element.two.location}} - {{d.type}}
        </div>
      </div>
```

as you can see, I tried to use `parseInt` in the switch, but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there another possible solution, avoiding the loop, to achieve this?

Here's a pen you can use to see what I mean:

http://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/ZBZNwe

Comment: If finally you will have to loop, you should prefer to do it *server side*. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AngularJS 1.5.7 the `orderBy` function was extended by an additional comparator - that's basically what you're looking for. The code you shared uses AngularJS 1.5.3 in the ionic bundle where this functionality is not yet supported.

Basically that's

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data | orderBy: order : false : mySortingFunction">
```

and this for the JavaScript part

```
// AngularJS' default compare function
// (defaultCompare() was taken from AngularJS 1.5.7 directly)
var defaultCompare = function(v1, v2) {
    var result = 0, type1 = v1.type, type2 = v2.type;
    if (type1 === type2) {
      var value1 = v1.value;
      var value2 = v2.value;
      if (type1 === 'string') {
        // Compare strings case-insensitively
        value1 = value1.toLowerCase();
        value2 = value2.toLowerCase();
      } else if (type1 === 'object') {
        // For basic objects, use the position of the object
        // in the collection instead of the value
        if (angular.isObject(value1)) value1 = v1.index;
        if (angular.isObject(value2)) value2 = v2.index;
      }
      if (value1 !== value2) {
        result = value1 < value2 ? -1 : 1;
      }
    } else {
      result = type1 < type2 ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return result;
};

// initialize order type
$scope.order = 'element.one.id';
// custom sorting function
$scope.mySortingFunction = function(v1, v2) {
  if ($scope.order !== 'element.one.id') {
    // fallback to default compare function
    return defaultCompare(v1, v2);
  }
  if (v1.value === v2.value) return 0;
  return (parseInt(v1.value) < parseInt(v2.value) ? -1 : 1);
};
```

The method `defaultCompare()` is AngularJS' default function which is unfortunately part of the internal API and not accessible - that's why it's copied to have a fallback to the default sorting behavior.

See the [AngularJS documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/docs/api/ng/filter/orderBy#using-a-custom-comparator) for more details.

Comment: I have changed it so that it uses 1.5.7 but it still doesnt work. If you open the console, the code is stopped by a debugger and if you paste this: angular.version.full it will print ot the version currently in use

Comment: I've updated to example to actually solve the problem - the previous one just outlined the usage of the comparator function. In your code `$scope.order` must be initialized to a value - if that's not done, the objects' index order is taken. Hope that helps...